# Invalid XML document when Updating xml field with string longer than 10M

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to update an xml type field in a PostgreSQL table with a large string.  If the length of the data is >10M characters I am getting an error back from the server.  We are using UPDATE instead of INSERT because we had trouble inserting just the xml field, so we ported all the other records/fields leaving the xml for last.

Has anyone seen this before?  Maybe know a away around it?  Is the server configured wrong?

We are using the latest JDBC driver (9.3-1102) and server 9.3.4 64-bit.

This is the code we are using:

```
    org.postgresql.Driver.setLogLevel(org.postgresql.Driver.DEBUG);
    Connection connDB = SampleApp.getPostgresConnection(connInfo);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileEntry);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(fis);
    reader.useDelimiter("%&#");

    try {
      connDB.setAutoCommit(false);

      while (reader.hasNext()) {
        String id = reader.next();
        id = id.replaceAll("\n", "");
        String line = reader.next();
        line = line.replaceAll("\'", "\'\'");

        String updateQuery = "UPDATE OMF SET XML_FILE = XMLPARSE ( DOCUMENT  \'" + line + "\' ) WHERE ID = " + id;
        try {
          System.out.println("length: " +line.length() +" queryLen=" +updateQuery.length());

          PreparedStatement preStatement = conDB.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
          preStatement.execute();
          preStatement.clearParameters();
          preStatement.close();

          connDB.commit();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println("Error updating id#" +id);
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      // this just means EOF
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("FileNotFoundException with file " +fileEntry.getPath().toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

This is the error message:

```
10:42:26.805 (1)  <=BE ErrorMessage(ERROR: invalid XML document
  Detail: line 187341: internal error
        groupNumber="0" groupname="" integrationtime="62" nchannels="1"

                   ^
```

Comment: Can you send a example as psql script? It is looks like PostgreSQL or libxml2 bug. 10 MB is strange number, maybe it is related to work_mem, although I don't think. You can try to increase work_mem. Please, send a simplified test case (as psql script).
you can try to recheck a validity of long string (md5 for example). Is possible, so long string is broken elsewhere, and this bug is only first visible impact.

Comment: Using pgAdmin, the obvious update command would be 'UPDATE omf SET xml_file = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>.... (10MB of text)...' WHERE ID = 123456;'  That throws the same error shown above.

Comment: I tested successfully to store xml with 120MB. I found a internal limit 10MB in libxml2 https://answers.launchpad.net/lxml/+question/65510 .. this issue can depend on your XML. Can you increase a verbosity of logged messages? It can show a source of error from PostgreSQL source code - log_error_verbosity http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Comment: Excellent info!  Sounds like I probably want to leave the 10MB limit as a security feature and find another way around the problem.  Maybe I can load the data into an XML document and use XPath to load it into the database.  That is slower, but probably more future proof.  Thanks Pavel.